# How to embed my own video player in Facebook?

Tags: php, jquery, flash, facebook, video

Is it possible to embed my own video player in Facebook, so I can see the video directly in the timeline, like all the YouTube videos?

Are there any metatags I need to include in the <head> section of my site?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You must first get your Flash player approved by submitting a [video embed whitelist request](http://www.facebook.com/help/contact.php?show_form=video_embed_whitelist).

Once this is approved, which took 4 hours for me when I look back on emails from my request, your player will be able to be shown just as YouTube videos are. You can then use the Facebook Share help guide which [fire](https://stackoverflow.com/users/261970/fire) mentioned in his reply. Also, another helpful thing is the [URL Linter](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint/) which tells you how Facebook is interpreting the metadata on your pages.

Comment: The link to the "video embed whitelist request" is no longer active.

Comment: Whitelisting no longer required.

Comment: Anybody have a recent (2015) answer to this question?

Answer (score 15):

To add to the other answers, a recent developer post from Facebook (which I can't seem to find at the moment) inferred that whitelisting was no longer necessary. I did it anyway. Takes about a week.

You need to use the Open Graph protocol. Info on embedding video is at the bottom of this page: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/

This is what we found through experimentation (which will certainly change in the future):

- The player must be a flash player.
- It must be an https link.
- You can add optional flashvars as parameters.

An example og:video tag from our website:

```
<meta property="og:video" content="https://indieflix.com/media/swf/player.swf?bufferlength=3&lightcolor=FFFFFF&autostart=true&file=http%3A%2F%2Findieflix.com%2Fstreamer%2Fhdtrailer%2F32310_320x180.mp4&provider=http&frontcolor=CCCCCC&image=http%3A%2F%2Fcdn.indieflix.com%2Ffilms%2Fimages%2Flarge%2F32310.jpg&backcolor=333333" />
```

Comment: How about sizes, I can't find any size information. I mean width + height. Is there a maximum or minimum width/height? Thanks.

Comment: [Here is the post.](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/486/) "Previously, this required that your domain get added to a whitelist. We have now opened this up to every domain. "

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a meta tag though I am not sure if your own Flash video player will get directly embedded. Take a look at the *[Sharing Rich Media](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/share)* section.

Comment: Thanks alot for the link. But it doesnt work for me. Facebook dosen't show the thumbnail when i'm trying to share my link? :s

Answer (score 0):

Nice Video embed works like a charm just saw a recent change how youtube embed.
Previews it was a smals thumbnail with a play button , even when marked as favorite story.
Now they embed video as featured story (the star) full Timeline cover sized Thumbnail with the play button .that is very interesting for any video or flash embed in facebook.