# How to embed my own video player in Facebook? 2013 Version

Tags: facebook, video

I have seen it is possible to embed my own video player (hosted on my own domain) in Facebook, so I can see the video directly in the timeline, like all the YouTube videos.

- The question is, how exactly do these pages do it? What are the requirements to get it working?
- Is it also possible to embed all .swf files on Facebook, regardless whether they're videos?

---

[Note: You do not have to whitelist your domain first (=old version).](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4591764/how-to-embed-my-own-video-player-in-facebook)

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/property-types/#video

Comment: See My full answer on this question [how to share a video from my website on facebook like youtube](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18903890/2151050)

Answer (score 1):

You need one more metatag
 og:video:secure_url

This problem is might happen when users are trying to view the video from a secure page.