# Uploading AWS data onto facebook feed

Tags: iphone, facebook, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

We have a video capturing device, which uploads 20 MB clips to the cloud (on AWS S3). These clips are displayed on an iPhone app directly from the AWS S3 data.

We want to provide the user an option to share these feeds onto facebook. For doing so we want to avoid downloading the video locally onto the phone, and rather upload the data directly from cloud to facebook feed.

What are our options for uploading videos directly from the S3 onto user's facebook profile?

Since the only requirement here is to upload the video, I am trying to avoid developing a full fledged facebook app on the cloud. https://aws.amazon.com/facebook-application-hosting/

Comment: You could upload the video with the url where you uploaded it to S3 using https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/video-uploads, or you could also make an HTML Page where the video would be embedded, set its OG metatags and then let the user share that HTML Page URL.

Comment: @corvuszero: Thanks for your suggestion. I'm using the OG metatags method. While the image gets displayed on fb page, it's not possible to directly playback over there. How can I possibly achieve that. Do I need to embed an obselete media player such as the flash player? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4591764/how-to-embed-my-own-video-player-in-facebook